# update using case and sum statements

Tags: mysql, sql

After I run this query, I get an error message sating invalid use of group function.  Im pretty sure its after the case statement, I need an "AS amount" or "AS i.amount" but mySQl doesn't like any of those either.  Any suggestions?

```
update INVITATION AS i 
 LEFT JOIN REGISTRATION AS r on i.id=r.INVITATION_id 
 LEFT JOIN FUNDING AS f on r.id=f.REGISTRATION_id 
 SET i.funding_travel_amount =  SUM(case
when f.category = "Other" then sum(amount) 
when f.category = "Airfare" then sum(amount)
when f.category = "Mileage" then sum(amount)
else 0 end), i.funding_travel = "Custom" 
 WHERE i.funding_hotel = "Prepaid" 
 and i.funding_travel = "None" 
 and i.funding_per_diem = "None" 
 and (f.category = "Other" OR f.category ="Airfare" OR f.category= "Mileage")
 and f.id is not null;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use a `CASE...WHEN` if you are selecting rows with only those three values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query formated so it is more readable (at least to me):

```
update INVITATION i LEFT JOIN
       REGISTRATION r
       on i.id=r.INVITATION_id LEFT JOIN
       FUNDING AS f on r.id=f.REGISTRATION_id 
    SET i.funding_travel_amount = 
            SUM(case when f.category = "Other" then sum(amount) 
                     when f.category = "Airfare" then sum(amount)
                     when f.category = "Mileage" then sum(amount)
                     else 0
                end),
       i.funding_travel = "Custom" 
     WHERE i.funding_hotel = "Prepaid" and
           i.funding_travel = "None" and
           i.funding_per_diem = "None"  and
           (f.category = "Other" OR f.category ="Airfare" OR f.category= "Mileage") and
           f.id is not null;
```

Onee problem is obvious -- you have sum statements within sums.  I would write this with a correlated subquery:

```
update INVITATION 
    SET funding_travel_amount = 
            (select SUM(case when f.category = "Other" then amount
                             when f.category = "Airfare" then amount
                             when f.category = "Mileage" then amount
                             else 0
                        end)
             from Registration r join
                  Funding f
                  on r.id=f.REGISTRATION_id and
                  invitation.id = r.invitation_id
            ),
       funding_travel = "Custom" 
     WHERE funding_hotel = "Prepaid" and
           funding_travel = "None" and
           funding_per_diem = "None"
```

This is not exactly the same, because it will update the amount even when none of the categories are avaialble.  You can fix that with an additional condition on the `where`.

Comment: @ Gordon, when I try your query I get the error that reads Invalid use of group function.

Comment: @user2232926 . . . I originally answered too quickly.  I saw the `sum()` within a `sum()`, and that triggered my response.  I would write the query using a correlated subquery, which I've now included as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should remove the **sum** before amount.

Comment: I've also tried the following:  As you can tell im quite new at this.

Comment: update INVITATION AS i 
 LEFT JOIN REGISTRATION AS r on i.id=r.INVITATION_id 
 LEFT JOIN FUNDING AS f on r.id=f.REGISTRATION_id 
 SET i.funding_travel_amount = 
  (SELECT SUM(SUM(f.category = "Other" + f.category = "Airfare" + f.category = "Mileage"))), i.funding_travel = "Custom" 
  WHERE i.funding_hotel = "Prepaid" 
  and i.funding_travel = "None" 
  and i.funding_per_diem = "None" 
  and (f.category = "Other" OR f.category ="Airfare" OR f.category= "Mileage")
  and f.id is not null;

Comment: ok, I suggest you to share your table schema definition and some sample data, desired result. Then people can help you quickly.